# Updating context on one child resetting all the states

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have multiple components with checkboxes. This function is called on onChange on checkboxes.

```
  const { selectedDocuments, setSelectedDocuments } = useContext(Context);
  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(false);

  const onSelect: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> | undefined = (
    e
  ) => {
    if (isSelected) {
      setSelectedDocuments((docs) =>
        docs.filter((doc) => doc.data.id !== card.data.id)
      );
      setIsSelected(false);
    } else {
      setSelectedDocuments((docs) => [...docs, card]);
      setIsSelected(true);
    }
  };
```

I am trying to update the context and flip the check state. But every time context is updating the state of component `isSelected` is getting reset (on very other children which is using the same context).

I am not sure why all the states are getting reset.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple components which are instances of a single component.
for example, you could have a `<Checkboxes/>` component and then you are simply reusing it everywhere.
If you are doing this then I think you will run into trouble with Context API.
You can define separate and unique state variables and then pass these state variables as props to each component to solve this issue.

For example say you have state variables selectedOne, selectedTwo,selectedThree ....

then you can do something like this

```
<Checkboxes selected = {selectedOne} />
<Checkboxes selected = {selectedTwo} />
<Checkboxes selected = {selectedThree} />
```

Comment: Yes, I am using multiple instances of a single component. It is working fine when I am passing the variables as props. Any idea why changing from the component does not work ?

Comment: A Principle I learnt recently when working with React,Redux is to never mutate the state directly. In React state immutability is important. When we need to update state we should update it(by returning new copy of state) but not make changes to existing state.